# Какое ограничение на количество индексов в таблице mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql

Добрый день, уважаемые знатоки.

Суть: Имею таблицу, уже на 26 столбцов. В таблице уже 9 индексов, на полях содержащих ключи на родительские таблицы. Хочу проставить индексы на поля содержащие штампы времени, в перспективе возможны еще поля, также желательные к индексации.

Вопрос: Существует ли и если существует, то какое ограничение на количество индексов (индексируемых столбцов) в таблице mysql (5.0.77)?

PS: Видел только вопрос, про [ограничение на количество индексов в mssql](http://www.sql.ru/Forum/actualthread.aspx?bid=1&tid=158377&hl=).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в 4.0.20 было 32
в 5.х.х - хз...

Таблички на 26 столбцов как то не очень смотряться, подумайте лучше над вопросом рефакторинга базы данных

Comment: Да, сам чувствую, что не то и не туда.
Извиняюсь за наглость. Не подскажете литературу или статью по рефакторингу? Яндексом пользоваться умею, хотелось бы что-то, что помогло вам в личном опыте.